# How to configure WebSockets (RFC 6455) in Netty 3.3?

Tags: websocket, netty

I have Netty 3.3 server with WebSockets from https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server

I have client that implement RFC 6455, but server can't decode it's messages by default. While debugging, I see that WebSocket08FrameDecoder is used (instead WebSocket13FrameDecoder). When I downgrade client to draft00 everything works fine.
How do I configure Netty to decode RFC 6455 messages?

**update**

Client send this handshake package:

```
GET /websocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 5a087
Host: 127.0.0.1
Origin: 127.0.0.1
```

And the handshaker on the server is `WebSocketServerHandshaker13`, but I still get error:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.CorruptedFrameException: unmasked client to server frame
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:350)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:138)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:56)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:465)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:438)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look in [WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocketServerHandshakerFactory.java), it instances the decoder based on the web socket version passed in the HTTP header.

```
 public WebSocketServerHandshaker newHandshaker(HttpRequest req) {

    String version = req.getHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION);
    if (version != null) {
        if (version.equals(WebSocketVersion.V13.toHttpHeaderValue())) {
            // Version 13 of the wire protocol - RFC 6455 (version 17 of the draft hybi specification).
            return new WebSocketServerHandshaker13(webSocketURL, subprotocols, allowExtensions);
        } else if (version.equals(WebSocketVersion.V08.toHttpHeaderValue())) {
            // Version 8 of the wire protocol - version 10 of the draft hybi specification.
            return new WebSocketServerHandshaker08(webSocketURL, subprotocols, allowExtensions);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // Assume version 00 where version header was not specified
        return new WebSocketServerHandshaker00(webSocketURL, subprotocols);
    }
}
```

Please check your client implementation to see which version it is sending in the HTTP header. It should be `Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13`.

Comment: I add client handshake package and debug log to answer

Comment: It should be problem in client masking. Thank you for your response.